# Finding the values of this complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to find the values of $(1 - i\sqrt{3})^i$ in terms of $a + bi$. First I found $r$ which was $2$ and $\theta$ which was $5\pi/3$ or $-\pi/3$. So $z = 2e^{i\theta}$ all to the i power but I'm lost on what to do from here.

Comment: I'm also not sure why my equations aren't showing up properly, I think I'm following everything correctly from the latex guide

Comment: You just gotta put your latex between dollars signs so the system knows it's latex.

Comment: So to type $5\pi/3$ for example is `$5\pi/3$`

Comment: Oh ok thanks, I didn't know you needed the dollar signs as well

Comment: Your $r$ and $\theta$ are good; now raise them to the $i$ power

Answer (score 2):

$$(2e^{i\theta})^i = 2^i e^{-\theta} = e^{i\log 2} e^{-\theta}$$ and use $ e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$ from here...

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't that expression equal $e^(ilog2 - $\theta$)$, so how can you use cosx + isinx in this case

Comment: @HokieFan7 $e^{-\theta}$ is a real number, you can isolate that and apply the formula for $e^{i \log 2}$.

Comment: Ohh i see it now, so it becomes (cos(log2) + isin(log2))*exp(-pi(6n+5)/3). Does it matter if I use log or ln or is it interchangable

Comment: @HokieFan7 That’s correct. $\ln$ and $\log$ usually both refer to base $e$ in math.

Answer (score 2):

Since $1-i\sqrt{3}=2\exp\frac{5\pi i}{3}=\exp\left(\ln 2+\frac{\pi i(6n+5)}{3}\right)$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$, $(1-i\sqrt{3})^i$ is multi-valued with possible values $\exp\left(i\ln 2-\frac{\pi(6n+5)}{3}\right)$.

Comment: Can you explain how you got to the last line real quick, I'm still sort of lost

Comment: @HokieFan7 It's using the usual $(\exp z)^w=\exp zw$, with the caveat that, because $z$ isn't unique given $\exp z$, in general we get multiple choices for $zw$, each with their own resulting value of $\exp zw).